# How to apply patch to make pod phase go to Succeeded or Failed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-python-client

This is a follow-up from my last question - [How to programmatically modify a running k8s pod status conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64881584/5291015) after which I realized, you can only patch the container spec from the deployment manifest to seamlessly let the controller apply the patch changes to the pods through the ReplicaSet it created.

Now my question is how to apply patch to make the Pod phase to go to `Succeeded` or `Failed`. I know for e.g. for pod phase to go to `Succeeded`, all the containers need to terminate successfully and shouldn't be restarted. My intention is to not modify the original command and arguments from the container image, but apply a patch to introduce a custom command which will override the one from the container image.

So I attempted to do below to run `exit 0` as below

```sh
kubectl -n foo-ns patch deployment foo-manager -p '
{
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "container1",
            "command": [
              "exit",
              "0"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "container2",
            "command": [
              "exit",
              "0"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But since my container file system layers are built from `FROM scratch`, there aren't any native commands available other than the original executable supposed to run i.e. `exit` as a built-in is not even available.

What's the best way to do this? by patching the pod to make it transition to either of those Pod phases.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, or do? Pods are intended to be "immutable", so it is not meant to be modified. Here, you modify the `Deployment`, that is a good way. If you want to "stop" an app, I would set `replicas: 0` then the running Pods are terminated. Or are you trying to do anything different?

Comment: @Jonas: I'm trying to do something more than just delete, from - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase, the pod goes through multiple phases when it starts up. Basically I'm testing one of my custom controllers can catch a pod's phase (and act on it) when it is stuck in a certain state e.g. `Pending`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to apply patch to make the Pod phase to go to Succeeded or Failed

Pods are intended to be **immutable** - don't try to change them - instead, replace them with new Pods. You can create [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) directly, but mostly, you want to work with [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) that is replacing the current ReplicaSet for every change on the Pod-template.

> Basically I'm testing one of my custom controllers can catch a pod's phase (and act on it) when it is stuck in a certain state e.g. Pending

All Pods goes through those states. For testing, you can create [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) directly, with different binaries or arguments.

To test Pod phase `Pending` you could, log the *phase* in your controller when watching a Pod? Or you can mock the pod - so that it is in phase Pending?

I don't know *kubernetes-python-client* but `client-go` does have [Fake-clients](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/fake) that can work with Pods, including `UpdateStatus`.

```
func (c *FakePods) UpdateStatus(ctx context.Context, pod *corev1.Pod, opts v1.UpdateOptions) (*corev1.Pod, error)
```

Now, looking at the Python client, it does seem to lack this feature: [Issue #524 fake client for unit testing](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/524)